# Calculate Positive Likelihood Ratio when Specificity is 1

Tags: biostatistics

The Positive Likelihood Ratio is calculated:

`LR+ = sensitivity / (1 - specificity)`

If you have a test with a specificity of 100%, how can we calculate the LR+ as there is now a 0 in the denominator `(1-1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should remember what LR+ means. It is

> the probability of a person who has the disease testing positive divided by the probability of a person who does not have the disease testing positive.

Taken from the Wikipedia article.

If the specificity is 100% the there are not false positives so it is reasonable to consider LR+ as $\infty$